# Turn pandas datetime to hour:min rounded to 15 min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

I read this excell sheet (only column of 'DATEHEUREMAX') with pandas using this command:

```
xdata = read_excel('Data.xlsx', 'Data', usecols=['DATEHEUREMAX'])
```

[image: exemple of my excel sheet]

now I want to turn this df into a simplify df with only hour:min rounded to 15min up. The main idea is to plot an histogram base on hour:min

Comment: Please post the data, not an image of the data.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to round the data. You may just need to use the proposed solution under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/can-pandas-plot-a-histogram-of-dates

Comment: Or even better try out this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814606/a-per-hour-histogram-of-datetime-using-pandas/34820891

Comment: I think @CedricZoppolo has the right idea here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following DataFrame, with a single column, read as *datetime* (not *string*):

```
                  Dat
0 2019-06-03 12:07:00
1 2019-06-04 10:04:00
2 2019-06-05 11:42:00
3 2019-06-06 10:17:00
```

To round these dates to 15 mins run:

```
df['Dat2'] = df.Dat.dt.round('15T').dt.time.map(lambda s: str(s)[:-3])
```

The result is:

```
                  Dat  Dat2
0 2019-06-03 12:07:00 12:00
1 2019-06-04 10:04:00 10:00
2 2019-06-05 11:42:00 11:45
3 2019-06-06 10:17:00 10:15
```

For demonstration purpose, I saved the result in a new column, but you can
save it in the original column.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for

```
rounded_column = df['time_column'].dt.round('15min').strftime("%H:%M")
```

although i agree with the commenters you might not really need to do this and just use a timegrouper

Comment: realy close, how to get rid of date part, keep only "10:45" ?

Comment: my goal is to plot an histogram to know the frequency of each date

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to round your column in order to get a histogram of dates with your `DATEHEUREMAX` column. For this purpose you can just make use of `pd.Grouper` as detailed below.

### Toy sample code

You can work out this example to get a solution with your date column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Generating a sample of 10000 timestamps and selecting 500 to randomize them
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('2015-01-14'),periods = 10000, freq='S'), 500),  columns=['date'])
# Setting the date as the index since the TimeGrouper works on Index, the date column is not dropped to be able to count
df.set_index('date', drop=False, inplace=True)
# Getting the histogram
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).count().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

This code resolves to a graph like below:
[image]

### Solution with your data

For your data you should be able to do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xdata = read_excel('Data.xlsx', 'Data', usecols=['DATEHEUREMAX'])
xdata.set_index('DATEHEUREMAX', drop=False, inplace=True)
xdata.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).count().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```